# Inequality $||f-g|| < \epsilon \Rightarrow |E[f] - E[g]| < \epsilon$

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $C(X)$ be the space of continuous bounded functions on some metric space $(X,d)$. Can it be shown that if

$||f-g||_\infty < \epsilon$ if follows that $| \int f \, \text{d}P - \int g \, \text{d}P| < \epsilon$

where $f, g \in C(X)$ and $P$ is a Borel probability measure?

I know if $f\leq g$ then $\int f \, \text{d}P \leq \int g \, \text{d}P$ or one/both of the integrals are undefined, however this does not help.

Maybe this can be proven with convergence: Let $h = f-g$ and $h_n \uparrow h$, then the above should be equivalent to
$\lim_{n \to \infty} ||h_n|| < \epsilon \Rightarrow |\int h_n \, \text{d}P| < \epsilon$

It is part of a proof I try to understand. The paper is university intern and I already contacted the author, but no response from him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that 
$$\left|\int f\mathrm dP-\int g\mathrm dP\right|\leqslant \int |f-g|\mathrm dP
\leqslant P(X)\lVert f-g\rVert_\infty=\lVert f-g\rVert_\infty.$$